# VPN error 800, when remote but not locally

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, firewall

I am going to spend a few days in my summerhouse, and i would like to have access to all my media on my server so i am trying to set up a VPN.

I have followed a guide, and i am abe to connect to the VPN using my local ip "10.0.0.1" but when i use my remote ip "sogaard.us" do i get an error 800.

I have followed almost all guides so far but have been unable to fix the problem, so my last resort is to ask here.

As i can connect via local network but not remote is my guess that the problem lies within the router, but as i can see is it set up correctly.
[image]
Outbound firewall on the server:
[image]
Inbound firewall on the server:
[image]
RRA security setup:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error if the subnet is the same on both ends.

I.E both local network (that you are connecting from) and remote network (that you are trying to connect to via VPN) has the same subnet like: 10.0.0.xxx
Therefore, it is a good idea NOT to use same subnet on your business network which you will be VPNing to.

If the problem persists Ping the VPN remote IP/domain to ensure it is available.

Comment: My subnet is 10.0.0.x, and the computer that i have tested the remote login from is on an 192.168.1.x subnet. How ever i i connect locally on the same subnet with the local ip do i connect without any problems.